# What could cause this sporadic error in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

On rare occasion I get the following error and stack trace when someone access one of my ASP.NET applications:

> *Error*: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> *Stacktrace*: at **MyApp.MyDefaultPage**.Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

OK a few things here. `MyApp.MyDefaultPage` does not have a defined `Page_Init` of my own so there is no additional code (I understand the event still fires). Also there is no base class code which it would run through either in a Page_Init event, so I am at a loss from where this is occuring.

The only thing I could even gather is I have a `Global.asax` exception handler code in the Application_Error event, but the **1st** thing I do before accessing any objects is make sure they are Not Nothing before trying to access (to prevent any errors).

Any clue as to what could cause this sporadically?

Comment: could you put the code of the page?

Comment: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` is probably the single most common ASP.NET error period. You're trying to reference the methods or properties of a `null` object most likely. Does your exception have an inner exception?

Comment: have you checked your event viewer?

Comment: @ivowilblo - as I mentioned there is no code to reference from the page for where the StackTrace is pointing to. And posting a few hundred lines of binding and visual manipulation code over multiple methods is too much to post here

Comment: @Justin - No inner exception, and I am well aware of this exception and why it is caused as I mentioned in my original post: **"...but the 1st thing I do before accessing any objects is make sure they are Not Nothing before trying to access (to prevent any errors)."**

Comment: I saw that, but it's still the cause of the error in some way. You wouldn't get that exception if it weren't, though sometimes it can be caused by your `aspx` page. What's the code of your `page_init`?

Comment: @Afshin - Yes I checked the event viewer for each web server in the farm. It did *not* even report to the log. I believe it happens on application creation for the client and in the initial Init stages. To be honest if I knew it was not affecting the client, and just an exception being reported in the global handler, then I could just ignore it.

Comment: @Justin - from original post: *MyApp.MyDefaultPage does not have a defined Page_Init of my own so there is no additional code (I understand the event still fires). Also there is no base class code which it would run through either in a Page_Init event, so I am at a loss from where this is occuring.*

Comment: I knew as soon as I posted this would be difficult to help with and truly am not surprised if it can't be figured out and that's OK. I wish I had more details to post but I do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using any of the Ajax controls?

If so make sure your scriptmanager tag is the first item after your form tag

also give a try to setting EnableEventValidation="false" for the page.

It could be caused by user interaction with the page before the page is fully loaded.

Comment: The exceptions would be consistent if this were the problem.

Comment: Yes I am using AJAX and the AJAX Control Toolkit (latest build from codeplex). It *is* the 1st line in the Master Page right after the form tag: <form id="form1" runat="server"> <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>  I don't want to just arbritraily set EnableEventValidation="false" because there are security reprocussions to that. However overall, I too wondered if this was some problem with AJAX loading a script on occasion.

Comment: As I mentioned before - I don't want to just arbritraily set EnableEventValidation="false" because there are security reprocussions to that. However there is no activity on this so maybe mark it up to an AJAX script not loading on occasion or something.